# Execute Salesforce Apex from external app without saving any apex code in Salesforce Org and also without opening environment

Tags: node.js, rest, salesforce, apex-code

Is there a way to execute Salesforce Apex code without saving any apex code in Salesforce Org and also without opening environment?. I already have a Connected App through which I am able to access fields through API calls.

I want to implement a feature similar to "Execute Apex" in the workbench(please open images) in  Application built in nodejs.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Kxu.png)   [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNRoE.png)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the [executeanonymous()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_calls_executeanonymous.htm) soap call, which I believe is what the workbench uses

Comment: Thanks :)  it helped .. i am using Tooling API

Comment: great happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try sfdx apex commands

apex:execute

Executes one or more lines of anonymous Apex code, or executes the code in a local file.

Command Syntax

```
sfdx force:apex:execute

[-f APEXCODEFILE]
[-u TARGETUSERNAME]
[--json]
[--loglevel LOGLEVEL]
```

Parameters

-f | --apexcodefile APEXCODEFILE
Optional
Path to a local file that contains Apex code.

Type: filepath

-u | --targetusername TARGETUSERNAME
Optional
A username or alias for the target org. Overrides the default target org.

Type: string

--json
Optional
Format output as JSON.

Type: flag

--loglevel LOGLEVEL
Optional
The logging level for this command invocation. Logs are stored in $HOME/.sfdx/sfdx.log.

Type: string

Permissible values are: trace, debug, info, warn, error, fatal
Default value: error

Help for apex:execute

Executes one or more lines of Apex code, or executes the code in a local file.

Before you enter code, run this command with no parameters to get a prompt.

From the prompt, all commands are executed in a single execute anonymous request.

For more information, see "Anonymous Blocks" in the Apex Developer Guide.

Examples:

```
$ sfdx force:apex:execute -f ~/test.apex

$ sfdx force:apex:execute
>> Start typing Apex code. Press the Enter key after each line,
>> then press CTRL+D when finished.
```